# Binding saved phone number to vue tel input for the purpose of editing

Tags: vue.js, vue-tel-input

I am using vue-tel-input for entering a phone number.

Phone number entry

```
<vue-tel-input
    v-model="phonenumber"
    @validate="telValidate"
></vue-tel-input>
```

Method to check it is valid:

```
telValidate(telnumber) {
    this.validatedphonenumber = telnumber.number;
    this.validphonenumber = telnumber.valid;
},
```

Method to update phone number:

```
this.$axios.put("users/" + this.accountId, {
    phonenumber: this.validatedphonenumber
});
```

So this will update the user with the complete telephone number as a string such as "+447766554433"

I am now trying to display this saved string in a vue-tel-input for the case of editing it. My questions are:

Firstly how do I bind the saved value to the vue-tel-input?

Secondly am I right in thinking that I would have to save the countryCallingCode and the nationalNumber from the number object sperately or is there way of extracting the two parts from the single stored value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `vue-tel-input` with `autoformat`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      phonenumber: null,
      validNumber: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    telValidate(telnumber) {
      if (telnumber.valid) {
        this.validNumber = telnumber.number
      } else {
        this.validNumber = ''
      }
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      INPUT:<br />
      <vue-tel-input
        v-model="phonenumber"
        @validate="telValidate"
        autoformat
        :dropdownOptions="{
          showFlags: false,
          showDialCodeInSelection: true,
        }"
      />
      <hr>
      EDIT:<br />
      <vue-tel-input
        v-model="validNumber"
        autoformat
        :dropdownOptions="{
          showFlags: false,
          showDialCodeInSelection: true,
        }"
      />
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-tel-input@5.3.0/dist/vue-tel-input.umd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-tel-input@5.3.0/dist/vue-tel-input.min.css">
<div id="app"></div>
```

It seems to me that `vue-tel-input` is not really good at parsing phone numbers. If you "feed" it with a formatted phone number, then it quite understands but doesn't really set itself up.

Comment: That's great. Seems to work so far as I have tested it. Thank you. I have just seen this in the docs but it is not clear. It seems a pretty basic requirement to cover. Thank you.